# universal contract WCF web service, OperationContract

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, universal, operationcontract

I have defined `OperationContract` as such in Interface.

```
[OperationContract(Action = "*")]
Message ProcessMessage(Message message);
```

On **Program.cs**, when I call

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client o = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
msgafterprocess = o.ProcessMessage(msg);
```

Getting Error ProcessMessage, does not exist in the current context. 
Please tell me, is it some syntax error?  Or I have misunderstood the accessibility of

```
[OperationContract(Action = "*")]
```

when calling from client side.

Comment: Remove (Action = "*") and try.

Comment: I want to access [OperationContract(Action = "*")]  , otherwise what's the point. It will be like a normal method.

Comment: What do you mean by *? What you are trying to do

Comment: I am trying to capture all the request messages as such ProcessMessage(message); will be called when any other method is called.